# Will splitting a furnace duct cause a problem?

Tags: furnace, ducts

[image]

I have two rooms (entry (1)) and (living (2)).

The House was built in 1900 and the two small rectangles 1 and 2 represent returns.

At this time only 2 is connect in the living room with a 6 " pipe form that furnace that is only like 7'long. Both rooms are 10'*13' roughly.

No idea why someone disconnected the #1 return but that rooms is always colder.

I am wondering if I could mount a 6 " Y off the pipe from the furnace and have both returns working without any issues?

If so , should I go 6" to two 4" or keep them all 6"?

Thank you,

John

Comment: it is not a Return, it is a Vent

Comment: Welcome! The short answer to "will splitting cause a problem" is "no, but it won't solve your problem either." If you can share any photos of the furnace and duct work that could help us assess whether you'll do best to add a new duct, enlarge the existing up to the point of the wye, or something else.

Comment: yes, that would help. keep them 6"; you're not adding any resistance,  you're removing it. Given the change, you might need to adjust the fan speed and slightly close one off to balance the rooms.

Comment: I don't have a full answer for you, but I do have this: you can almost never have too much return. Don't size down.